# Ubuntu cron shebang not working

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have a script with this as the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

When cron runs my script, I get this error `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`.

When i run the script as my user the script runs fine, just not as cron. I'm guessing it's because node is not on the PATH of the user that runs cron?

How can I get this shebang to work with cron?

`$ which node` gives me
`/home/myuser/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin/node`

Comment: why dont you try full path to `node` ?

Comment: Because i thought by using a shebang for node in the script is better than calling `$ node myscript.js`. I could be wrong though..

Comment: I am not an expert on js, but what happens if you say `#!/usr/bin/env /full/path/to/node`? Full path you get by `which node`, for example.

Comment: I would think that i don't want to do that b/c the path to node could be different for every user. See my edit to my question for what `which node` gives me.

Comment: last thing i would try is then `#!/usr/bin/env  $HOME/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin/node`. Probably without chance of success.

Comment: This is just bad practice to need the full path because that only allows the script to work on servers with node installed in this exact location. Even if that works, that defeats the purpose of the shebang in general..

Comment: @jaromrax that is just a bad approach. OP the problem might be because your env variables aren't set properly.

Comment: If i edit cron tab as my user via `$crontab -e`, doesn't that mean the cron job runs as my user? And if so why isn't the path set? Because if i run the script manually (without cron) it runs just fine.

Comment: @Catfish true but there must be something wrong.

Comment: Relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454

Comment: @Catfish why not try to check your `$PATH`? And add the nvm node there if it's not there yet. Then relog to the machine.

Comment: @majidarif - i am afraid that cron runs without environment defined usually in .bashrc, that

Comment: @Catfish - i agree on bad practice. But anyway you get to troubles, since user's $PATH is defined typically in .bashrc; Either you manage to run cron on bash or you define your PATH duplicitely at another place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cron jobs run in a restricted environment. In an interactive shell, your `$PATH` is probably set in your `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`. Cron jobs are executed in an environment that hasn't sourced those files, so your user-specific `$PATH` settings will not be available.

You can see what that environment looks like by temporarily creating a crontab entry like:

```
* * * * * printenv > crontab-environment
```

You can explicitly set `$PATH` in your crontab, either in the command itself:

```
* * * * * PATH=$PATH:/home/myuser/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin some_command
```

or in a separate line in your crontab:

```
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/home/myuser/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin
```

You can't (directly) use the usual `PATH=$PATH:/new/dir` syntax to append a directory to your `$PATH` in an environment setting line, because variable references are not replaced in such a line. They *are* processed in crontab command lines.

`man 5 crontab` for details.

Another option is to use an explicit full path in the script itself, changing

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

to

```
#!/home/myuser/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin/node
```

You'll need to customize this for each system where `node` is installed in a different place.  Or you can arrange for `node` (or `nodejs`?) to be installed in a consistent place.

Comment: I tried creating a temporary cron to print my env and I get this error: `/bin/sh: 1: printenv: not found`

Comment: That's odd. Does `/usr/bin/printenv` exist? It should be installed as part of the coreutils package. In any case, try `env` rather than `printenv` (but `env` is also part of coreutils). Or try specifying the full path to the `printenv` or `env` command.

Comment: `53 * * * * env > /var/log/cron.log 2>&1` gives me `/bin/sh: 1: env: not found`

Comment: What does `type env` at a shell prompt tell you? If the result is `env is /usr/bin/env`, replace `env` by `/usr/bin/env` in the cron job. (I'm beginning to think something is messed up on your system.)

Comment: `$ type env` gives: `env is /usr/bin/env`. This server is a pretty typical ubuntu 14.04 Digital Ocean box. Only thing i've done is installed node, nginx, and a few other modules. Nothing outta the ordinary.

Comment: So what does this mean i need to do to get my cron job to work with my script? Now i'm confused.

Comment: @Catfish: So am I. The default `$PATH` for cron jobs certainly *should* include `/usr/bin`. But as I suggested before, try replacing `env` by `/usr/bin/env` in your crontab entry. That should (a) fix the `env: not found` problem and (b) show you exactly what the actual `$PATH` setting is. I just tried this myself, with `* * * * *       /usr/bin/env > $HOME/.cronenv`, I get `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. Do you have any environment settings in your crontab?

Comment: So by changing env to /usr/bin/env in my crontab entry it out puts this: `HOME=/home/toymachiner62
LOGNAME=toymachiner62
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/toymachiner62`

Comment: See my updated answer. I asked before whether you have any environment settings in your crontab. Do you?

Comment: See my updated comment. I did have 1 line in there to add my node to the path. I took that out and updated my comment above. Now I just have the standard crontab with this line `12 * * * * /usr/bin/env > /var/log/cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: That one line is probably what messed up your `$PATH`. Now that you've removed it, the solutions I suggested in my answer should work.

Comment: You suggested this `PATH = $PATH:/home/myuser/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin` but `man 5 crontab` tells me that it does not parse variables so that is why I originally was setting the PATH and it caused `env` not to work without the full path.

Comment: @Catfish: My apologies, I missed that. See my updated answer.